# Unexpected Token in react while using fetch

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I have been learning it online.But I have some issues.Whenever I try to fetch the url it says 
Syntax error: C:/xampp/htdocs/react-project/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (14:10).I have followed the same step as the video but also I am getting the problem.Here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Flat from './components/flat';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      flats:[]
    }
}
  componentDidMount(){
    const url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/flats-boilerplate/master/flats.json";
    fetch url()
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="main">
          <div className="search">
          </div>
          <div className="flats">
          {this.state.flats.map((flat)=>{
            return <Flat flat ={flat} />
          })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="map">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI0vw.png)

I would be grateful for your help and sorry if I've done dumb mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple syntax error.It should be :

```
 fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(//dosomething)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace fetch url() with fetch(url) in line 14

Comment: i did a very silly mistake thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change the fetch like this way

```
const url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/flats-boilerplate/master/flats.json";

fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
    }).then(response =>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
```